# Could not install apk to Android Emulator

Tags: android, signalr

I am following a tutorial for this https://github.com/SignalR/java-client when I try to run the android code in my physical device or an emulator, I get this error:

```
Launching 'app' on samsung SM-S908E.

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

List of apks:
[0] 'D:\Tryouts\SignalR\Android\app\build\intermediates\apk\debug\app-arm64-v8a-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'Failed to commit install session 1833948652 with command package install-commit 1833948652. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113'
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

I tried putting this in my build.gradle (Module) in the android block:

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

This is the library I implemented:

[image]

And this is how I called it:

[image]

It builds successfully but still it doesn't install. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try Clean Build your code
2. Check your dependencies, experiment with other version of the same dependencies
3. You can try using [this one](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#gc) but you need to remove or comment `split` block cause it can cause conflict with `ndk` block

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
}
```